# Converting Normally Closed to Normally Open

Tags: transistors, relay, automotive, normally-open

I have a truck that has a different engine swapped into it.  I'm trying to get the cruise control to work and I've tracked the issue down to the Set/Coast switch.  The PCM is expecting a 12 V signal when the Set/Coast button is pushed.  Right now when the cruise is on there is a constant 12 V going from the switch to the PCM, and when I push the switch it drops to 0 V.  I tried using a relay by hooking the switch to 85, 12 V to 30 and 86 and the load to 87.  That didn't work.

Talking the stalk apart doesn't appear to be an option.  Rather, I should say talking the stalk apart is an option but getting it back together isn't.

Here is what I followed: https://www.the12volt.com/relays/converting-polarity.asp

Comment: Diagrams would help here. Why was the set/coast switch changed? Surely it was the engine that was changed?

Comment: A modification carried out in an automobile without proper understanding could endanger oneself and others on the road. Hence voting to close.

Comment: Once you insure and prove your NC to NO conversion works to SET the cruise control, how will you make sure the cruise control cancels properly with the brake pedal or the CANCEL button?  I think the only way is an actual road test at 40mph or more!

Comment: @SolarMike - The cruise control stalk was not changed, the engine and PCM were.

Comment: @vu2nan - This is a Duramax swap, it has been done on thousands of vehicles with plenty of documentation.  I understand exactly what needs to be done. I have documentation from Bosch, which is the company that makes the PCM.  There is no risk here.

Comment: @GTElectronics - I have proven this is what I want to do with a momentary switch, plus documentation from Bosch.  The truck had a cruise control setup before the swap.

Comment: How does the stalk switch work? Is it normally open, and when you press the button, it makes the curcuit? Is either side of the stalk switch already hard-wired with 12V or GND do you have the freedom to wire it however you want? If you are able to edit your question to add a diagram of the stalk switch operation and pre-existing wiring that would be great.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thank you for the clarification. I have retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you followed is to convert polarity, to convert NO to NC see: https://www.the12volt.com/relays/spdt-and-spst-automotive-relays.asp

Connections of coil: switch to 86, 85 to ground; NC contact: +12 V to 30 and output to PCM is 87a.

Comment: This worked, thanks!